# Adding 2 hexadecimals as strings

Tags: php, hex

### Description

I'm trying to get the data for a decall image for a Team Fortress 2 item from steam
http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2695676

### Data used

steam inventory item attributes

`"attributes": [
    {
        "defindex": 152,
        "value": 160020469,
        "float_value": 3.3154542658454145e-033
    },
    {
        "defindex": 227,
        "value": 142668139,
        "float_value": 7.7604768692394667e-034
    },
    {
        "defindex": 746,
        "value": 1065353216,
        "float_value": 1
    },
    {
        "defindex": 292,
        "value": 1115684864,
        "float_value": 64
    },
    {
        "defindex": 388,
        "value": 1115684864,
        "float_value": 64
    }
]`

### My script

`

```
function Function_BigDecimal_to_Hexadecimal_Converter($dec) {
    $hex = '';
    do {    
        $last = bcmod($dec, 16);
        $hex = dechex($last).$hex;
        $dec = bcdiv(bcsub($dec, $last), 16);
    } while($dec>0);
    return $hex;
}
function Function_BigHexadecimal_to_Decimal_Converter($hex) {
    $dec = 0;  $len = strlen($hex);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $len; $i++) {  $dec = bcadd($dec, bcmul(strval(hexdec($hex[$i - 1])), bcpow('16', strval($len - $i)))); }
    return $dec;
}

$hex1 = Function_BigDecimal_to_Hexadecimal_Converter('142668139' ); // data from defindex 227
$hex2 = Function_BigDecimal_to_Hexadecimal_Converter('160020469'); // data from defindex 152

echo 'hex1 ',$hex1,'<br>'; // = 880f16b
echo 'hex2 ',$hex2,'<br>'; // = 989b7f5


$hex_append =  $hex1.$hex2;
echo 'hex_append ',$hex_append,'<br>'; // = 880f16b989b7f5

$ugcid = Function_BigHexadecimal_to_Decimal_Converter($hex_append);
echo 'ugcid ',$ugcid,'<br>'; // = 38297187109156853
```

`

### My problem

expected ucid value shoud be `612754991346202613` and I got `38297187109156853`

Here i'm reversing this code to get hex_append from the expected answer

`echo 'Reversed hex_append using expected answer '.Function_BigDecimal_to_Hexadecimal_Converter('612754991346202613');// = 880f16b0989b7f5`

### Conclusion

The difference in hex_append calculated `880f16b989b7f5` and the reversed answer `880f16b0989b7f5` is a `0`
How can I fix this ?
I guess the a 0 needs to be added sometimes when adding 2 hexes as strings.
This problem was detected only for this item.

All this php code con be copyed in a php file and executed

Answer (score 0):

Answer: The string must have 18 characters