# adding 2 hexes as strings in php

Tags: php, hex

I want to add 2 hex numbers as strings

```
$Hex1 = '880f16b';
$Hex2 = '989b7f5';
$Added = $Hex1 . $Hex2; // = 880f16b989b7f5
```

Final answer shoud be `880f16b0989b7f5` when adding these 2 strings.
Why a `0` was added in the expected answer 880f16b`0`989b7f5 ?

The final code generated will be converted from hex to decimal

Comment: [norepro](https://3v4l.org/00rvh)

Comment: Why is the expected answer in need of the `0`? Where did you get that expectation from?

Comment: I extracted that final answer from http://backpack.tf/ That code generated is used to link an image on that website, My problem is that untill now I hadn't had a problem using this metod, but now for 1 item i can't get the correct number, I don't understand why that 0 was added

Comment: http://backpack.tf/ is an website that decodes the Team Fortress 2 backpack

Comment: i added more info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060010/adding-2-hexadecimas-as-strings

Comment: I just discovered that the final answer must be 18 characters long, (by comparing the length of multiple items that are similar)

Comment: You can post an answer from your own answer. So future reader can get benefit from reading this question.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: The string must have 18 characters